# How to remove extra array bracket from the response. Javascript

Tags: javascript, axios

I am getting data from an API. I need this response data to use outside of axios, not inside any function but globally available in JavaScript, HTML DOM.

```
let responseData = [];
axios
.get(url)
.then(res => {
 responseData.push(res.data.data);
});

console.log(responseData);
```

`console.log(responseData);` gives the output:

```
[]
```

inside this array is another array of objects `[{},{},{}]`

```
[[{},{},{}]]
```

But the format I need is `[{},{},{}]`

Any idea how should I approach this?

Comment: var whatYouWant = responseData[0];

Comment: Also, console log will log empty array because it is outside of `then`. Only after the call is successful, it will be populated [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321)

Comment: var whatYouWant = responseData[0]   | This giving undefined. already try this.

Comment: I know that works inside the then(() => { // here }).  I want to use outside the then, Also I don't want to pass the result to another function. The data needs to accessible globally. The data retrieve we can also assign as const. Thanks for trying to help really appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

try in this way:

```
responseData=responseData.concat(res.data.data);
```

Comment: That only outputs, first Object of the result and result looks like    [[{}]]  again it has 2 brackets.

Comment: Didn't work outside then